# Install R on windows nanoserver image using powershell

Tags: r, windows, powershell, docker, nano-server

I need to run some R scripts inside the Docker container. I searched for the available images , but those are only helpful for Linux. But , I need to run those on Windows container, as scripts are dependent on UI which requires .Net support. I tried

```
.\R-3.3.2-win.exe /q /ACTION=Install /IACCEPTROPENLICENSETERMS /INSTANCENAME= MSSQLSERVER /FEATURES=SQL_Shared_MR /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS
```

using powershell. But nothing is working out. Please suggest me , if there are any available images of R for Windows or how to install the exe file inside docker container.

Comment: [This](https://www.r-bloggers.com/rocker-is-now-the-official-r-image-for-docker/) might be helpful.

Comment: @ChirayuChamoli 
`docker pull rocker/r-base`
gives me  **Using default tag: latest** 

**_Pulling from rocker/r-base_**

**image operating system "linux" cannot be used on this platform**

Comment: I get this error ` TLS handshake timeout` while installing i dont think it would be OS dependent.

Comment: @ChirayuChamoli, I am unable to pull docker image of **rocker/r-base** . because I am using **Windows-native Docker Engine directly (that is, not using “Docker for Windows”)** [link](https://blog.docker.com/2016/09/build-your-first-docker-windows-server-container/).

Comment: Why are you giving that command in power shell. Arent you supposed to do everything inside the container?

Comment: @ChirayuChamoli the thing is that, I donot see any R studio image for Windows platform. So, I am trying to make one for myself using the exe file. So, I am trying to build one for myself. While building, I will not be able to go through setup process which is UI based like clicking `next` etc. So, only powershell or command prompt is available for me to install setup process.

Comment: if you read [this](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/) you can switch between linux and windows within the container. Anyways if you want to build a image for windows i think ppl here can hekl you out.